# Why does jquery.validate.js show error messages twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to create form with jQuery validation and this is my form, 
Then I am using this code to validate the inputs.

It's just plain and simple:

```js
$('#forgot_pwd').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        username: {
            minlength: 6,
            required: true,

        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Enter your Username"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Enter your Email",
                email: "Enter valid email address"
            },
        },

     errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.hide();
            $('.messagebox').hide();
            error.appendTo($('#alert-message'));
            $('.messagebox').slideDown('slow');



        },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
            $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
     <h4 class="l-login">Forgot Password</h4>
     <div class="messagebox">
      <div id="alert-message"></div>
     </div>
     <form class="col-md-12" id="forgot_pwd" method="POST">
       <div class="form-group form-float">
        <div class="form-line">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
         <label class="form-label">Username</label>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group form-float">
        <div class="form-line">
         <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
         <label class="form-label">Email</label>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <button id="signin" type="submit" class="btn btn-raised waves-effect bg-red" data-loading-text="Loading...">Reset Password</button>
    
       <a href="sign-up.php" class="btn btn-raised waves-effect" type="submit">SIGN UP</a><br/><br/>
      </form>
    </div>
```

As for me I am calling the error message box only once but it shows up twice.
Not sure why it shows up twice.

why is that?

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`invalidHandler`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#invalidhandler) function to empty it.

```
invalidHandler: function() {
    $('#alert-message').empty();
}
```

This will empty the `#alert-message` when the form is submitted and your rules fail. This will allow the `errorPlacement` function to be called multiple times without emptying `#alert-message` on multiple errors.

For example in your code.

```
$('#forgot_pwd').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        username: {
            minlength: 6,
            required: true,

        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        username: {
            required: "Enter your Username"
        },
        email: {
            required: "Enter your Email",
            email: "Enter valid email address"
        },
    },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.hide();
        $('.messagebox').hide();
        error.appendTo($('#alert-message'));
        $('.messagebox').slideDown('slow');
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
        $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
    },
    invalidHandler: function() {
        $('#alert-message').empty();
    }
});
```

Comment: where to put this? If I add this in my javascript code am getting this error message in console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: @RiffazStarr Just edited. You can put it after the `unhighlight` function. Just remember the comma after the end of the `unhighlight` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clear $('#alert-message') before adding new message to it.

```
 errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.hide();
        $('.messagebox').hide();
        $('#alert-message').empty() 
        error.appendTo($('#alert-message'));
        $('.messagebox').slideDown('slow');
```

Comment: This won't work if there are two errors. It will only show 1 error at a time then.

Comment: yes, as @CharlieFish says it shows only one error (last error) now if I add `$('#alert-message').empty();`

Comment: @RiffazStarr Just posted an answer that should fix this issue and show **all** current errors without duplicates.